# jQuery: weird behavior - XHTTPResponses vs promises/wrappers

Tags: jquery, ajax

Having this code:

```
(function($) {

    $(function(){
        $("div.cotizador ul > li > a.cotizador").click(function(){
            var data = {
                concesionaria: $(this).data("concesionaria"),
                modelo: $(this).data("modelo")
            };

            var promise = $.get("ir-a-concesionaria", data, function(data){
                if ("success" in data) {
                    window.location.href = data.success.redirect;
                } else {
                    alert("No se puede seleccionar el modelo especificado. Consulte con el administrador del sitio.");
                }
            }, "application/json");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(promise);
            promise.fail(function(xhr, errorType, errorDescription){
                alert("Ocurrió un error interno. Intente nuevamente más tarde");
            });
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

(Currently it doesn't matter which HTML actually triggers the callback).

When the instruction `console.log(promise)` is reached, Google Chrome shows in the console debug message:

```
XMLHttpRequest {statusText: "", status: 0, response: "", responseType: "", responseXML: null…}
```

This means: the returned result by $.get is not a promise-wrapped XHTTP (and so, the .fail method does not exist).

Meanwhile, debugging the `data` object gives a `{modelo:"xxx", concesionaria:"yyy"}` assuming "xxx" and "yyy" have well-defined and expected values (this means: data is defined and has no errors when the error I'm talking about is triggered).

**HOWEVER** when i copy-paste the code to console, and replace the `data` argument with a literal object, e.g.:

```
jQuery.get("ir-a-concesionaria", {modelo:'toyota-gt86', concesionaria:'casabaca'}, function(data){
    if ("success" in data) {
        window.location.href = data.success.redirect;
    } else {
        alert("No se puede seleccionar el modelo especificado. Consulte con el administrador del sitio.");
    }
}, "application/json");
```

The returned object (as seen in Google Chrome's console) is a promise-wrapped object (as told in the documentation).

**Question**: Why could this be happening?

(Even when this could be non-helpful: Currently i'm using Drupal 7)

Comment: It should just be `"json"`, as the 4th parameter to `$.get`.

Comment: Even then, getting the same error. Notice I used the SAME code in both parameters, and get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer (Drupal Sucks):

First, the 1.4.4 version of jQuery is loaded. Then, the function is called. Finally, the 1.10.1 version of jQuery is loaded. After that, I repeated the test case and, of course, it worked -.-''.